# chkconfig --add default runlevel

Tags: linux, runlevel, chkconfig

What is the default *runlevel* assigned when you run

```
chkconfig --add
```

for a program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chkconfig` doesn't change default run levels.  That's defined by `/etc/inittab` (pre-systemd) or `systemctl set-default` (on systemd).

What `chkconfig` does is create links to various run levels.

So let's take RedHat 6 (CentOS 6).

When you do `chkconfig -add myservice` then it will look in `/etc/init.d/myservice` for specific comment lines:

e.g

```
# chkconfig: 2345 55 25
```

The `2345` part means the service will be enabled at run levels 2,3,4 and 5.  So now `chkconfig --add` will create links `S55myservice` in `rc[2345].d` and `K25myservice` in the other run levels (`rc[016].d`)

Comment: Ohhh, ok. Thanks Stephen, appreciate your knowledge!

Comment: Actually, the a script present under /etc/init.d does not contain a "chkconfig" line in it. In this case, is what runlevel is assigned to this program?

Comment: On CentOS6 that'll create S50 scripts for 2,3,4,5 and K50 for 0,1,6